# App terminates due to uncaught exception

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, sigabrt

My app was working fine until I added another tab to the tab bar controller. I got SIGABRT. Then I undid everything to try and get it working again and now get this

> `***` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'

Can anyone help?

Comment: We need some code; otherwise we can't help.

Comment: I dont know what code you need to see....

Comment: Do you call setValue on an anonymous type(id)? Maybe you expect a certain type there but a the wrong instance is passed on. Are you using IB?

Comment: And perhaps go back and accept answers to some of your previous questions.

Comment: im using xcode 4. like it said it was working fine, i changed something that didnt work so changed it back to how it was - now i get the sigabrt

Comment: @Sam: Set breakpoints in the suspect areas to find the line(s) that cause the exception.

Comment: kirby Todd - yes sorry i will, i wasnt really aware thats what was done

Comment: Run your app with **Build and Debug**. When the crash happens, open up the the debugger console (Cmd-Shift-R) and type bt. Paste the back trace from the debugger console here.

Comment: This may help: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=556417

Comment: @sam if you wish to add more detail, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5405362/edit); do not add an answer for this purpose.  And, pelase, for everybody's sake--FORMAT.  If you dump a ton of text that causes [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to go crazy you might as well not add any text at all.  And it would benefit you to add the minimum amount of text from error messages as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your xib file(s) in Interface Builder and see if there are IBOutlets that got disconnected when you deleted your tab before. It's trying to connect an outlet that probably doesn't exist anymore.

[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect]

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with a NSDictionary ?
Be sure that you're working with Mutable object. This error can happen if you're inserting into a NSDictionary (instead of a NS**Mutable**Dictionary).
If not, maybe youre tab control indirectly use Dictionary